# how to set and save data in database in typo3

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have this code of the controller's index action.

```
public function indexAction() {
            $this->initContentObject();
            $titleforSocial = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['title'];
            $uidforSocial = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['uid'];
            $pidforSocial = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['pid'];
            echo "title: ".$titleforSocial . " uid: ". $uidforSocial . " pid:" .$pidforSocial;

            $elementUid = $this->cObj->data['_LOCALIZED_UID'] ? $this->cObj->data['_LOCALIZED_UID'] : $this->cObj->data['uid'];
            $buttonResults = $this->contentRepository->findByIdentifier($elementUid);
            $pagesResults = $this->pagesRepository->findByIdentifier($elementUid);
            $button_text = $buttonResults->getButtontext();
            $page_title = $pagesResults->setTitle('testing...');
            var_dump($button_text);
            $pagesResultsz = $this->pagesRepository->findByIdentifier($elementUid);
            var_dump($pagesResultsz);
            exit;
            $button_text = $this->cObj->data['buttonText'];
            $this->view->assign("button_text", $button_text);
    }
```

my main question is that how to save data to the database using set method of model. the current one sets 'testings...' when I dump but doesn't save it to database.
I am using typo3 7.6

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your object to repository which saves it to database. Method which you need to use differs depends on object already exists or it's new one.

For new object you have to use `add()` method:

```
$this->pagesRepository->add($pagesResults);
```

And for existing one use `update()`:

```
$this->pagesRepository->update($pagesResults);
```

Comment: I have already tried this 
$this->pagesRepository->update($pagesResults);
but it just set the value and not save it to the database.
do I need to define update() in my repository too?

Comment: If your repository extends `Repository` you don't have to. Try to inject `PersistenceManager` and after passing object to `update()` call `$this->persistanceManager->persistAll();`.

Comment: can you tell me that what is PersistenceManager and why we use it?
I am new to typo3 so don't know much about it.

Comment: In basic words it's an object which communicates with database. But right now I'm little bit confused. Are you using TYPO3 Flow or other TYPO3 family product?

Comment: I edited the tags, it's about TYPO3 CMS not Flow or Neos.